# Unwanted space on html because of bootstrap cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-cards

I keep getting unwanted extra space on the right side of the webpage whenever I'm adding bootstrap cards that looks like this: [image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgMy3.png), I'm trying to put everything inside of the sections ,does anyone know how to remove those space? thank you!

```
        <section id="section" class="container-fluid" style="background-color: steelblue;">
        <h1 id="bulletin">Bulletin Board</h1><br>
        <hr id="bulletin-divider">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
            <div class="col mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100" id="cards">
                    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="art preview">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">dasddsa</h5>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="card-text">ART DETAILS</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="art preview">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">dasddsa</h5>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="card-text">ART DETAILS</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not open your browser's developer console to inspect the additional spaces?

Comment: I fix it with resizing the padding. thank you!